# How to prevent page reload or refresh in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

```
$http.get("check_login.php")
.success(function(response) {
    if(response.login == 1 || response.login == 2) {
        window.location.href = 'new.html';
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(response.login == 0 || response.login == undefined) {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `event`? please include more code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn about `routing` in `AngularJs`, please go through these links.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating